# Converting matrix to dataframe : Works in one case, not another

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

Below is a snipped of the output of a sample session.  In it, I create a matrix with the `matrix()` function and simply convert it to a dataframe with the `as.data.frame()` function.  In the second section, I also create a matrix, but through a different process (the one I want to make work), but even though `str()` gives me analogous output, I get an error when converting to a dataframe.  Any ideas?

EDIT: At the end, I added a line where I (re)cast the matrix to a matrix, and then convert that to a data frame.  It works, but I shouldn't have to recast according to what I see in the `str()` output of the `test_mx` that fails to be cast as a data frame.  So I know how to fix, but I don't understand why I need to do that extra step to do so.

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) -- "Trick or Treat"

> library(reshape)
> ## This works
> ## ==========
> tmx = matrix(1:12*0.1, ncol=4)
> rownames(tmx) = c("A", "B", "C")
> colnames(tmx) = 0:3
> tmx
    0   1   2   3
A 0.1 0.4 0.7 1.0
B 0.2 0.5 0.8 1.1
C 0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2
> 
> str(tmx)
 num [1:3, 1:4] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "A" "B" "C"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "0" "1" "2" "3"
> as.data.frame(tmx)
    0   1   2   3
A 0.1 0.4 0.7 1.0
B 0.2 0.5 0.8 1.1
C 0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2
> 
> 
> 
> ## This does not
> ## =============
> t = 0:3
> thesd = 0.1
> dat = data.frame(
+     a1 = sin(2*pi*t/length(t)) + rnorm(t, sd=thesd),
+     b1 = sin(2*pi*t/length(t) - pi) + rnorm(t, sd=thesd),
+     c1 = sin(2*pi*t/length(t) - pi/2) + rnorm(t, sd=thesd),
+     t  = t
+ )
> 
> test_mx = cast(melt(dat, id.vars="t"), variable ~ t)
> tmp_rownames = as.character(test_mx[,1])
> test_mx = test_mx[,-1]
> tmp_colnames = colnames(test_mx)
> test_mx = as.matrix(test_mx)
> rownames(test_mx) = tmp_rownames
> colnames(test_mx) = tmp_colnames
> 
> str(test_mx)
 num [1:3, 1:4] 0.06211 -0.00596 -1.09718 1.1555 -0.96443 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a1" "b1" "c1"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "0" "1" "2" "3"
> as.data.frame(test_mx)
Error in data.frame(rrownames(x), unx, check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3
> 
> ## But this does work
> as.data.frame(as.matrix(test_mx))
             0           1           2           3
a1 -0.16166693  0.97479282  0.01471777 -1.01517539
b1 -0.01012797 -0.97745698 -0.12667287  0.96542412
c1 -1.07217297  0.06783235  1.12068282 -0.02012263

> ## why?
```

Comment: To the editor's note: I used `test_mx = cast(melt(dat, id.vars="t"), variable ~ t)`, which, where I ran, required the `reshape` package.  Without it, I get `Error: could not find function "cast"`.

Comment: Look into the `class`es and related `methods`, as I've described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17873683/1270695).

Comment: Also, in the future, please cut out those pesky `>` and `+` symbols from your code that make it difficult to copy-and-paste your code to test it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `reshape2`, not `reshape`, as the latter is obsolete.

Change also `cast`  by `dcast` or `acast`.

```
as.data.frame(test_mx)
            0           1            2           3
1 -0.08120468  0.97593052 -0.006127179 -1.15107784
2 -0.04165681 -1.02810193  0.004637454  0.99042403
3 -0.87862063  0.07346341  1.019113669 -0.01769976
```

Comment: Thanks!  Not only did that solve the cast to a data frame, but I didn't have to go through the machinations to get the row and column names right.  I wrote up a complete solution example here: http://pastebin.com/B2uEPy8M .  Would you be willing to use that as your solution code, just to have a complete recreateable example?

Answer (score 12):

While @agstudy's answer solves your problem and gets you up to date with the most recent packages, it doesn't go into trying to understand *why* this happens.

To understand why, step back to your line `test_mx = cast(melt(dat, id.vars="t"), variable ~ t)`. I'll create two objects here so we can do some comparisons:

```
test_mx <- test_mx_cast <- cast(melt(dat, id.vars="t"), variable ~ t)
class(test_mx)
# [1] "cast_df"    "data.frame"
class(test_mx_cast)
# [1] "cast_df"    "data.frame"
```

Hmm. What is this `cast_df` class? It turns out that the "reshape" method has gone and defined several new methods. See, for example, `methods(as.data.frame)` or `methods(as.matrix)`:

```
> methods(as.matrix)
[1] as.matrix.cast_df     as.matrix.cast_matrix as.matrix.data.frame  as.matrix.default    
[5] as.matrix.dist*       as.matrix.noquote     as.matrix.POSIXlt     as.matrix.raster*    

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
> methods(as.data.frame)
 [1] as.data.frame.aovproj*        as.data.frame.array           as.data.frame.AsIs           
 [4] as.data.frame.cast_df         as.data.frame.cast_matrix     as.data.frame.character      
 [7] as.data.frame.complex         as.data.frame.data.frame      as.data.frame.Date           
[10] as.data.frame.default         as.data.frame.difftime        as.data.frame.factor         
[13] as.data.frame.ftable*         as.data.frame.function*       as.data.frame.idf*           
[16] as.data.frame.integer         as.data.frame.list            as.data.frame.logical        
[19] as.data.frame.logLik*         as.data.frame.matrix          as.data.frame.model.matrix   
[22] as.data.frame.numeric         as.data.frame.numeric_version as.data.frame.ordered        
[25] as.data.frame.POSIXct         as.data.frame.POSIXlt         as.data.frame.raw            
[28] as.data.frame.table           as.data.frame.ts              as.data.frame.vector         

   Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

Notice above ^^ the first and second methods for `as.matrix` and fourth and fifth methods for `as.data.frame`.

What does this mean? Well, you went and wrote several lines after you created `test_mx` to convert your `data.frame` to a `matrix`. This was mostly because you wanted to make sure that your first column ended up as `rownames` and didn't coerce your entire matrix to a character matrix.

```
tmp_rownames = as.character(test_mx[,1])
test_mx = test_mx[,-1]
tmp_colnames = colnames(test_mx)
test_mx = as.matrix(test_mx)
rownames(test_mx) = tmp_rownames
colnames(test_mx) = tmp_colnames
test_mx
#               0           1            2          3
# a1 -0.079811371  0.82820704 -0.193860367 -1.1269632
# b1 -0.009402418 -1.19348155 -0.004519269  0.8921427
# c1 -0.784163111 -0.01340952  0.966208235  0.0135557
```

Because "reshape" has already defined a customized `as.matrix` method, you didn't actually need to do that!

```
as.matrix(test_mx_cast)
#               0           1            2          3
# a1 -0.079811371  0.82820704 -0.193860367 -1.1269632
# b1 -0.009402418 -1.19348155 -0.004519269  0.8921427
# c1 -0.784163111 -0.01340952  0.966208235  0.0135557
```

But that still doesn't exactly answer everything. To understand further, compare the two matrices now:

```
> test_mx_cast_matrix <- as.matrix(test_mx_cast)
> class(test_mx)
[1] "cast_matrix" "matrix"     
> class(test_mx_cast_matrix)
[1] "cast_matrix" "matrix"     
> str(test_mx)
 num [1:3, 1:4] -0.0798 -0.0094 -0.7842 0.8282 -1.1935 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a1" "b1" "c1"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "0" "1" "2" "3"
> str(test_mx_cast_matrix)
 num [1:3, 1:4] -0.0798 -0.0094 -0.7842 0.8282 -1.1935 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "a1" "b1" "c1"
  ..$ : chr [1:4] "0" "1" "2" "3"
 - attr(*, "idvars")= chr "variable"
 - attr(*, "rdimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ :'data.frame':    3 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "a1","b1","c1": 1 2 3
  ..$ :'data.frame':    4 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ t: int [1:4] 0 1 2 3
```

Hmmm. When we use `as.matrix` directly, all of the `attributes` that the "reshape" package adds are retained, but when we do the process manually, it still claims to be the same `class`, but all the custom `attributes` have been stripped.

So what?

Well, since R thinks that `test_mx` is a `cast_matrix`, when you call `as.data.frame`, it actually calls `as.data.frame.cast_matrix`, not `as.data.frame.matrix`.

Looking at how `as.data.frame.cast_matrix` is defined, those `attributes` are ***essential*** to recreate your `data.frame`, hence your errors. Here are the guts of the function:

```
> as.data.frame.cast_matrix
function (x, row.names, optional, ...) 
{
    unx <- unclass(x)
    colnames(unx) <- rownames(rcolnames(x))
    r.df <- data.frame(rrownames(x), unx, check.names = FALSE)
    class(r.df) <- c("cast_df", "data.frame")
    attr(r.df, "idvars") <- attr(x, "idvars")
    attr(r.df, "rdimnames") <- attr(x, "rdimnames")
    rownames(r.df) <- 1:nrow(r.df)
    r.df
}
<environment: namespace:reshape>
```

So, you now have three options:

1. Upgrade to "reshape2" -- Good advice, but keep in mind that there are still a good number of people who haven't bothered to make the switch.
2. Use "reshape" correctly, which requires looking a bit more at the `str`, `class`es and `attributes` of the objects it creates. Using it "correctly" here would have been to use `as.data.frame(test_mx_cast_matrix)`.
3. Specify the `method` you want to use (which is pretty safe when you don't know if packages are redefining methods--often, when they create new classes, you should also check to see if new methods have been created). Compare:

   ```
   > as.data.frame(test_mx)        ## Calls `as.data.frame.cast_matrix` ERROR!
   Error in data.frame(rrownames(x), unx, check.names = FALSE) : 
     arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 3
   > as.data.frame.matrix(test_mx) ## Specifies the `as.data.frame` method. WORKS!
                 0           1            2          3
   a1 -0.079811371  0.82820704 -0.193860367 -1.1269632
   b1 -0.009402418 -1.19348155 -0.004519269  0.8921427
   c1 -0.784163111 -0.01340952  0.966208235  0.0135557
   ```

Sigh. The end....

Comment: Have a +1 for effort. That equals `1.3e-3` votes for each word in your answer.

Comment: @thelatemail, better than a 0 for each word!

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!  Seems like "Using reshape correctly" is a bit hard to do -- where do you learn about those conventions of the most straightforward way to do the converstions, rather than hacking a solution out, like I did?

Comment: @mpettis, Hadley didn't document the "value" portion of the help pages for those functions. That's where  package authors usually mention such things. Get into the habit of looking at the `class`, `attributes`, and `str` of your objects. That might raise a flag. Some users like to call specific methods and functions directly to avoid ambiguity in their code since so many R functions are quite overloaded (`plot`, `summary`, and `print`, for example). Eg: if you have both "reshape" and "reshape2" loaded, but want to make sure you're using `cast` from "reshape2", you can use `reshape2:::cast()`.