# rowSums breaks on one-column data.frame generated by cast in library(reshape) -- why?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

Here's some code -- I don't understand why rowSums breaks when it does, and why changing the class of test3 fixes it.  This seems bizarre.  Is it a bug?  If not, what am I missing?

```
library(reshape)

test <- data.frame(x=1:5)
rowSums(test)  # Works
class(test)  # "data.frame"

## Trying to break rowSums; see below
class(test) <- c("data.frame", "cast_df")
rowSums(test)  # Works, but see below

vars <- c("x", "y", "z")
test2 <- data.frame(label=rep(c("A", "B"), c(3, 3)),
                    variable=rep(vars, 2),
                    value=1:6)

test2.cast <- cast(test2, label ~ variable, value="value")

rowSums(test2.cast[, vars])  # Works
rowSums(test2.cast[, "y"])  # Breaks because of drop=TRUE

test3 <- test2.cast[, "y", drop=FALSE]
rowSums(test3)  # Why does this break?
class(test3)  # c("cast_df", "data.frame")
class(test3) <- "data.frame"
rowSums(test3)  # Works!  Why?
```

Context:  I have a large data frame generated by cast. I then programmatically call rowSums on several different subsets of columns of that data frame -- and I noticed this behavior when the subset had only one column. This is a small reproducible example.

Comment: The answer might be: Don't do that. OR use `reshape2::dcast`

Comment: Related question and [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17873683/1270695) here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowSums` calls `as.matrix`. The first two lines of `as.matrix.cast_df` are:

```
ids <- attr(x, "idvars")
mat <- as.matrix.data.frame(x[, setdiff(names(x), ids)])
```

Note the lack of `drop = TRUE` there. When you reset the class to just `data.frame` this method isn't called, instead the regular `as.matrix.data.frame` method is called directly, and there's no problem.

Comment: I thought `reshape` was superseded by `reshape2`?

Comment: @DWin It was, and I probably should have mentioned that in my answer, in that bug reports on `reshape` maybe aren't really relevant at this point.